show that if $(\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \theta) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, 1))$ then $(Y_n \overset{P}{\to} \theta)$
I have the following question:
Show that if $(Y_n)$ be a sequence of random variables that satisfies $(\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \theta) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, 1))$ then $(Y_n \overset{P}{\to} \theta)$.
I've proceeded as follows but I'm not sure if I'm formally correct:

First, I start with the given condition:
$$
\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \theta) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, 1)
$$
I can divide both sides by $(\sqrt{n})$. Using the Continuous Mapping Theorem, which states that if $ (X_n \overset{d}{\to} X)$ and $(g)$ is a continuous function, then $(g(X_n) \overset{d}{\to} g(X)$, I get:
$$
Y_n - \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sqrt{n}(Y_n - \theta)
$$
Therefore,
$$
Y_n - \theta \overset{d}{\to} \frac{Z}{\sqrt{n}} \quad \text{where} \quad Z \sim N(0, 1)
$$
Next, considering the asymptotic behavior, since $(Z \sim N(0, 1))$, I know that:
$$
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{n}} \overset{d}{\to} 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty
$$
This implies:
$$
Y_n - \theta \overset{d}{\to} 0
$$
and hence:
$$
Y_n \overset{d}{\to} \theta
$$
Finally, I use the result that if a sequence of random variables $(X_n \overset{d}{\to} c)$ where $c$ is a constant, then $(X_n \overset{P}{\to} c)$. Therefore:
$$
Y_n \overset{d}{\to} \theta \implies Y_n \overset{P}{\to} \theta
$$
Thus, I have shown that $$Y_n \overset{P}{\to} \theta$$

I've doubts about this step:$$
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{n}} \overset{d}{\to} 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty
$$
I might be supposed to use Slutsky's Theorem around here. I couldn't make up my mind.
I appreciate the help.
Flaw of the above Argument: It turns out I can't use Continuous Mapping Theorem if $g$ is a function of n.

If $n$ is moving, you cannot divide by a limitless function of $n.$

According to Slutsky's theorem, if $Z_n \xrightarrow{d} Z$ and $a_n \xrightarrow{p} a$, then $a_n Z_n \xrightarrow{d} a Z$. Here, $Z_n=\sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-\theta\right)$ and $Z \sim N(0,1)$, and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{p} 0$.
We consider:
$$
Y_n-\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-\theta\right)
$$
Since $\sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-\theta\right) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{p} 0$, it follows that:
$$
Y_n-\theta \xrightarrow{p} 0 .
$$
Convergence in probability implies that for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(\left|Y_n-\theta\right| \geq \epsilon\right)=0 .
$$
Thus
$$
Y_n \xrightarrow{p} \theta.
$$

Wouldn't the theorem conclude that $Y_n-\theta \xrightarrow{d} 0$, instead of $Y_n-\theta \xrightarrow{p} 0$? Then we know it converges to a constant (zero in our case). Thus we conclude if  $Y_n-\theta \xrightarrow{d} 0$,then $Y_n-\theta \xrightarrow{p} 0$.

\begin{equation}
\text { If } X_n \xrightarrow{d} c \text {, where } c \text { is a constant, then } X_n \xrightarrow{p} c \text {. }
\end{equation} @ZedVeZed

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $K>0$. Notice that for large enough $n$ you have $\sqrt{n}\epsilon>K$. Therefore
$$
\eqalign{
\limsup_nP\left(|Y_n-\theta|>\epsilon\right)
&=\limsup_nP\left(\sqrt{n}|Y_n-\theta|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon\right)\cr
&\le \limsup_nP\left(\sqrt{n}|Y_n-\theta|>K\right)\cr
&=2(1-\Phi(K)),}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf. The final equality follows because $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta)$ converges in distribution to the standard normal. As $K\to+\infty$, the upper bound above converges to $0$. Thus
$$
\limsup_nP\left(|Y_n-\theta|>\epsilon\right)=0,
$$
for each $\epsilon>0$. This shows that $Y_n \overset{P}{\to} \theta$.
